# Does a large or larger creature, only partially in darkness, see?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, vision-and-light, creature-size

If a large or larger creature is partially in darkness (magic or mundane), can it see out of it? Imagine a 4x4 zone of darkness, a large creature who's by half into the darkness, and the same creature is looking outside of the darkness.

I would think so but want to know what the rules say.

Comment: Can you expand the scenario please? Depending on if they are trying to see into the darkness or into the light will affect the answer.

Comment: I'll edit to better reflect the scenario

Comment: In the future, you do not have to signal edits, you can just make the alteration(s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've looked up as many different rules about vision and lighting as I can find, and none of them covered the scenario you have laid out.

I started off with [Vision and Light](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/vision-and-light/) under game mastering, but had nothing on size. So I moved to [Vision and Light](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/exploration-movement/#Vision_and_Light) under exploration, also nothing. So I went to the best source of information when it comes to size, the [space, reach, and threatened area](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates/) but this had nothing to do with vision.

I finally looked at something that would resemble this, and that is the [obscuring mist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/o/obscuring-mist/) spell. It has nothing to do with size, but someone in the mist has reduced vision.

So, assuming you are not using the facing rules, and your large+ creature does not have anything except normal vision, if half the creature is standing in the darkness and they are attempting to see out into the light on the side where their body is not in the darkness, then it would be assumed that the creature has stuck their head outside the darkness. Same would be true if you had a huge (3x3) creature and it had 6 of its 9 squares in the darkness. Trying to see past the darkness works as expected, it cant see through the darkness.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, if the darkness does not affect all the squares the creature occupies, the creature can still see from her non darkness squares.

Darkness is just a source of total concealment, which defines itself as the absence of line of sight.

> **Total Concealment**: If you have line of effect to a target but not line of sight, he is considered to have total concealment from you.

Although **line of sight** is not defined in the Corerulebook, it is usually inferred from the [concealment rules](https://legacy.aonprd.com/coreRulebook/combat.html#concealment), that supports the creature chooses from which corner to determine concealment.

> To determine whether your target has concealment from your ranged attack, **choose a corner of your square**. If any line from this corner to any corner of the target's square passes through a square or border that provides concealment, the target has concealment.

Also the rules of determining [cover for big creatures](https://legacy.aonprd.com/coreRulebook/combat.html#cover) support the idea the creature chooses from which point to determine sight.

> **Big Creatures and Cover**: Any creature with a space larger than 5 feet (1 square) determines cover against melee attacks slightly differently than smaller creatures do. Such a creature can choose any square that it occupies to determine if an opponent has cover against its melee attacks. Similarly, when making a melee attack against such a creature, you can pick any of the squares it occupies to determine if it has cover against you.

Finally, it might be illustrative to think on this scenario in the same way as when a large creature peeks around a corner.